# JQuery - If last element visible add class to buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using this plugin to scroll a list up and down. I would like to disable the buttons when the last element of the list is visible.

- Use down arrow to scroll.
- Reach end of list.
- Disable down arrow.

I have tried to use if :last-child :visible but of course that didn't work as the elements are always visible.

I have added the JS in fiddle for ease-of-use. http://jsfiddle.net/NuCWS/

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code from what I've done in the past:

```
$('#arrow_left').live('click', function(){
  if($('.browse_box:first-of-type').hasClass('active') != true){
    $('.browse_box.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    $('.browse_box_container_inside').animate({
       left: '+=549'
    },200);
   }
});

$('#arrow_right').live('click', function(){
   if($('.browse_box:last-of-type').hasClass('active') != true){
      $('.browse_box.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
      $('.browse_box_container_inside').animate({
         left: '-=549'
      },200);
   }
});
```